# Moving pgfplot axis ticks from axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

My ticks are touching the axis. Is there anyway of moving these further from the axis? [image]

Comment: Yes, there is. Does that answer your question? If you want the answer to be more explicit, please consider making your question more explicit by adding a minimal working example that produces the output you show.